# if/else statements vs dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

If I were to write a statement using dictionary instead of an else statement, how would that be? For example, say I have

```
def determineRank(years):
     if years == 1:
         return "Freshman"
     elif years == 2:
         return "Sophmore"
     elif years == 3:
         return "Junior"
     else:
         return "Senior"
```

If I were to rewrite this using dictionary, it would be

```
rank = {"Freshman":1, "Sophmore":2, "Junior":3, "Senior", ???}
```

what number would I write for the else?

Answer (score 5):

Use `.get` method with default value as second argument:

```
rank = {1: 'Freshman', 2: 'Sophmore', 3: 'Junior'}
rank.get(years, 'Senior')
```

Comment: Yes, except the OP's `rank` dictionary has years as values, not keys

Comment: @vaultah Doesn't matter. If necessary, you can switch values like `rank = dict((y,x) for x,y in old_rank.iteritems())`

Comment: You *had* to do that in order to make `rank.get` work as expected, so it actually does matter.

Comment: If you look at my code that I've posted, you see that key values are years. So that's correct. The main question is how to write if/else statement with a dictionary, so I assume that he can make up his dictionary in the way he wants and that it hasn't to be exactly in the way which is demonstrated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dictObject.get(key, defaultValue)`.

So, the equivalent to your function would be:

```
rank = {1: "Freshman", 2: "Sophmore", 3:"Junior"}.get(year, "Senior");
```

Note that the key/value pairs of the dictionary is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand upon what's already been posted here, using `dict.get` won't raise a `KeyError` when the key, e.g. 'Senior', isn't already in the dictionary.

You could also do something like this, utilizing the ternary operator to check whether a given year is already a key in `rank`:

```
rank = {1: "Freshman", 2: "Sophomore", 3: "Junior"}
year = 4
year_rank = rank[year] if year in rank else "Senior"
```

`year_rank` will be "Senior"

I think the `dict.get` method is a bit better, though.